# Looking for outline minor mode for OCaml buffers (with Tuareg and Merlin)

Tags: emacs, ocaml, outline, tuareg, merlin

I am missing one feature in emacs Tuareg mode: an outline of the current OCaml buffer with a list of top-level definitions. There is a similar feature in Proof General mode for Coq which I find very useful. If there is an additional package or some undocumented feature like this?

Below is a screenshot how this looks in Proof General:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a image to show what this feature looks like in Proof General mode?

Comment: And you can take a look at Imenu https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Imenu.html https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode https://github.com/bmag/imenu-list

Comment: @TianshuWang I've added screenshot to original post